# I don’t know why “The arguments is” not “The arguments are”

Tags: grammatical-number

When I studied EIKEN Grade 1 which is one of English examination in Japan, I saw the sentence below.

> The **arguments** of these oppressive governments **is** that personal
>   freedom must be sacrificed for public safety.

I think the sentence is wrong because the one is used “is” not “are”.
Is it correct?

> The **arguments** of these oppressive governments **are** that
>   personal freedom must be sacrificed for public safety.

Answer (score 3):

The "arguments ... is" version is definitely wrong.  Your suggested replacement is grammatically correct, but doesn't make much sense since only one argument is given. I'd suggest changing "arguments" to "argument" and (therefore) keeping the singular verb "is".  (I think the "s" in "arguments" was probably just a typo.)

Comment: Dear Andreas Blass. Thank you for your comment. I didn’t know that the “arguments” is a typo. I can understand the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

All those "oppressive governments" in that sentence agree on **one argument**, the argument that "personal freedom must be sacrificed for public safety". So it should be,

> The argument of these oppressive governments is that personal freedom
>   must be sacrificed for public safety.

Comment: Dear q-l-p. Thank you for your comment. Thanks to your explanation about “one argument”, I can understand the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Dear Taka, I am glad I could help. Please read the following: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers